# Why do we need to implement configure() in Guice Modules?

Tags: java, guice

I am having the following code:

```
public class XYZModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    private XYZ provideXYZ() {
        return new XYZ(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Does empty configure() method serve any purpose here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You don't need it anymore

Since [Guice 4.2](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice42), [the `configure()` method isn't `abstract`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#configure--) anymore. So you can get rid of it in your modules if you don't use it. Here's what the release notes say about it:

> `AbstractModule.configure()` is non-`abstract` to allow modules with only `@Provides`/`@ProvidesIntoSet`/... methods.